# Check string after cat command in bash

Tags: string, bash

How do I check if a string is contained in the text produced by a `cat` command in bash? I want to execute a certain action if the string is found in the text.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the expected output and preferably descibe the _certain action_, as well. We'd also love to see whay you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, using the pipe :

cat my_file | grep my_string

```
if [ ! $(cat my_file.txt | grep my_text) == "" ]
  then echo "exists"
else 
  echo "not exists" 
fi;
```

Comment: Thank you David. Could something like this work#!/bin/bash
if [(cat my_file | grep my_string) == my_string]
then
 echo "hello world"
else
 echo "ciao mondo"
fi

Comment: I edited my answer, I tried locally and it works @FlyBob

Answer (score 0):

Piping to grep is fine if it's a one-time match. Otherwise in bash you can match strings using patterns (==) or regexes (=~) like this:

```sh
# date looks like "Mon, Jun 22, 2020 11:04:54 AM"
today=$(date)
[[ $today == Mon* ]] && echo "It's the start of the week"
[[ $today =~ ^(Tue|Wed|Thu) ]] && echo "It's the middle of the week"
[[ $today == Fri* ]] && echo "Thank God It's Friday!"
```

This is really a comment on the other answer - you can just directly test the exit status of a command

```sh
# grep succeeds (exit status 0) if there's a match
# grep -q is to suppress the output of the matched line
# we just care whether there is a match or not

if grep -q my_text my_file.txt; then
  echo "exists"
else 
  echo "not exists" 
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
if grep -q my_text file; then
    echo "exists"
else 
    echo "not exists" 
fi
```